# Looping inside an eagerly loaded closure in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using function of Laravel eloquent model. 
Here is the code:-

```
$keywords = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];

$authors = App\Author::with(['books' => function ($query) use ($keywords) {
    // $query->where('name', 'like', '%name2%');

    foreach ($keywords as $name) {
        $query->orWhere('name', 'like', "%$name%");
    }
}])->get();
```

I am trying to return all authors along with books where the name of the book matches the values in a given array of keywords. I have used foreach loop to go through multiple `orwhere()` like conditions, but the condition does not seem to be working. However, the commented out statement is working fine for me.

Comment: Could it be that the first loop needs to be a `where` then the subsequent loops chain `orWhere` on to it?